# Does NetBeans 7 support JavaFX Script?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, netbeans-7, javafx-1

Does NetBeans 7 support JavaFX 1.x / JavaFX Script? I am  trying to install the plugin but i couldn't
make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and this is that I saw:

As announced at the JavaOne conference, JavaFX Script language will be discontinued. Therefore, future releases of NetBeans will not offer support for JavaFX Script. We recommend that developers who need this specific feature use NetBeans 6.9.1.

NetBeans 7.1 which will focus on support for Client Java and JavaFX Java APIs, amongst other things.

[link](http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1498.html)